# HAProxy redispatch on request 5xx errors

Tags: haproxy

Is there any option to re-dispatch a request if it gets failed with any **5xx** http status code. I tried **"option redispatch"** but this is for connection failure. How I can resend the request to backend servers once the request is failed with **5xx**. I think in conjunction with **if [condition]** we can do but I did not find any related documents for this.